# Is there a way to use the Youtube API using less code?

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, youtube, youtube-api

I did some tests to find a way to play an embed video from youtube and it stops others videos of the page that is playing in the moment.
I reached the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Youtube players test</title>

  <style type="text/css" >

  li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

  </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <ul id="videos">

  <li>Video1</li>

        <iframe id="player1" class="video" type="text/html" width="400" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <li>Video2</li>

    <iframe id="player2" class="video" width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3TAUnYZpMbA?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <li>Video3</li>

    <iframe id="player3" class="video" width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9U38GB2qVWA?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

 </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var primteste = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    primteste.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, primteste);

    var players = new Array(); 
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        players[0] = new YT.Player('player1', {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayer1StateChange
            }
        });

        players[1] = new YT.Player('player2', {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayer2StateChange
                }
            });

      players[2] = new YT.Player('player3', {
        events: {
          'onStateChange': onPlayer3StateChange
        }
      });

        }

      function onPlayer1StateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
          var x = 0;
          for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
          if (i == x) {
            i++;
          }
          players[i].stopVideo();
        }
       }
      }

      function onPlayer2StateChange(event) {
          if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
          var x = 1;
          for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
          if (i == x) {
            i++;
          }
          players[i].stopVideo();
        }
       }
      }

      function onPlayer3StateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
          var x = 2;
          for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
          if (i == x) {
            i++;
          }
          players[i].stopVideo();
        }
       }

      }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The code above satisfies my initial intention of play/stop videos and here goes my question. I did with only three videos and It's not too great for three, but I have a page that has more than 20 embed videos and with the way I coded I will have to code the same for each one of the videos what it will take lines and lines. Because I thought a lot and I couldn't figure out a simpler way to do it. 
Could someone gives me a light about this situation? Is there someone that sees a better way to do the same?

Thanks

Comment: you are just using javascrit?, nothin serverside like php?

Comment: See: loops (for adding the operations to n items),  DOM manipulation (for adding the elements, although it is likely the iframe should be reused). JQuery, which is already added helps with both.

Comment: @Shocklo why would he need to use PHP for this?

Comment: @Vinay just asking to make things easy, it can be done in javascript, but i think if he is using some server side like php, it would be even easy.

Comment: The only way I can see the PHP helping is if there is coordination logic that needs to happen between multiple clients. It seems like this script is completely client-side logic, so javascript seems best suited. The javascript here is trying to stop another video on screen if any other is played. Not sure how PHP will help there or make things easier.

Comment: Sorry - being very methodical in how I comment. Not trying to be one of those arrogant StackOverflow know-it-alls.

Comment: I find it very useful to wrap up an API or SDK in my own class for 2 reasons. 1. I get to learn the API a bit more while I look up how to do what I need and make the class / object. 2. A lot of SDKs or APIs (such as quickbooks) requires a lot of tediousness. In the quickbooks example, you have to load 5 classes to make an invoice. In this scenario making a new class and having a createInvoice method is ideal for me.

Comment: @Jesse exactly. Almost always when someone says they're looking at too much code, it's because they're neglecting good software architecture fundamentals. Namely, useful abstraction via encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the same onPlayerStateChange callback for all your players and stop all but the current player. To check if this is the current player, use `event.target != players[i]`.

Here's your example with a few tweaks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Youtube players test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        li {
            list-style: none;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <ul id="videos">
        <li>
            <h4>Video 1</h4>
            <iframe id="player1" class="video" width="400" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h4>Video 2</h4>
            <iframe id="player2" class="video" width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3TAUnYZpMbA?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h4>Video 3</h4>
            <iframe id="player3" class="video" width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9U38GB2qVWA?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Insert youtube API
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var primteste = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        primteste.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, primteste);

        var players = [];

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            // Populate 'players' with all the youtube iframes
            var videoIframes = document.getElementsByClassName('video');
            for(var i=0; i<videoIframes.length; i++){
                players.push(
                    new YT.Player(videoIframes[i], { // here we can pass an iframe element or an id
                        events: {
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    })
                );
            }
        }


        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                for (i=0; i<players.length; i++) {
                    // Stop all but the current player (the one that triggered the event)
                    if(players[i] != event.target){
                        players[i].stopVideo();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code will automatically add new players to the `players` array as long as the iframe holding the player has the class `.video`.

You don't need to have an `id` for each iframe but I left them there just in case you're using them somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude. This is the thing that I tried to find, but I couldn't code it in a functional way with only one yt.player. And the iframes' ids will be really used in another part.

Answer (score 0):

```
function _getOnPlayerChangeHandler(playerIndex) {
  return function (event) {
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if (i !== playerIndex) {
          players[i].stopVideo();
        }
      }
    }
  };
}

function _createPlayer (selector, playerIndex) {
  return new YT.Player(selector, {
    onStateChange: _getOnPlayerChangeHandler(playerIndex)
  });
}

players[0] = _createPlayer('player1', 0);
players[1] = _createPlayer('player2', 1);
players[2] = _createPlayer('player3', 2);
```

If you have more information about the player in the `event` object, you may not even have to create the handler from a factory like the one I've made.

Comment: Thanks bro for your answer.

Comment: No problem! As I said, if there's more information about the player in the `event` object, you can get rid of the factory/indexing. :-)